# Persistent field in Android service

Tags: android, serialization, persistence

I need to retain a complex object in my service, so I can reliably come back to it (it holds updates). Initially I coded it just as a class filed in my Service implementation but I'm observing that the updates object is periodically reset to null which tells me that server class itself is recreated. Can someone recommend lightweight reliable strategy to save and recreate such updates object (I can make it serializable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your service is restarted, the `onStop()` and `onStart()` methods are called. You can use the `onStop()` method to save your data to a persistent location, e.g. an application `sqlite` database. You can restore the data when `onStart()` is called.

You can read about using an `sqlite` database on the android developer [website](http://developer.android.com).

Comment: I think the problem is not with onStop and onStart but with fact that to serve these methods Android may create a new instance of the class. I really don't want to go sqlite db route since that would be another expense in already expensive processing. I'm looking into serialization/deserialization for lighter alternative

Comment: After onStop() is called, your service instance will be killed. That's why the method is called: one way or another, you need to save your data here. 

If you don't want to use a database, you can save a file using Context.openFileOutput(). You can read it later on (e.g. when onStart() is called) using Context.openFileInput()

Comment: So following this route: if I have a String filed in my Service class then it seem more efficient to read/write that on onStart/onStop and otherwise use it as a class field rather than read/write it to the SharedProperties each time the variable is needed

Comment: I know it's been some time, but saving data in the onStop() method (or the onDestroy() method that is now used) is not reliable, as the method is not always guaranteed to be called if the system is low on memory.  Just a note for those who stumble upon this question.

Comment: `android.app.Service` does not have an `onStop()` method, and `onStart(android.content.Intent, int)` is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

If I was doing it, I would use SharedPreferences. If it's too complex for that, I agree with @Scharrels about using a sqlite DB (which would, most likely, be the Google recommendation since their examples use sqlite in the smallest of cases, which implies it has a reasonable level of performance).

I've found SharedPreferences to be useful in a number of cases. First, being a key-value pairing store, a variety of different data can easily be stored, plus you could encode your objects into a string, if need be, and store them in a single field. Second, you can use multiple SharedPreference stores by simply retrieving ones under a different name (while still keeping them private). Finally, I find them easy to use since getting data and storing data is literally only a couple of lines of code (not counting any data munging or serialization you might need).

Comment: Bear in mind that SharedPreferences are stored in an XML file and, therefore, are not transactionally guaranteed.

Comment: Sure. And, depending on the real complexity of the objects that need to be persisted, may be less efficient than a small sqlite db. Coding-wise, though, would be very fast to get something in place for persistence, compared to the existing solution of nothing. On the plus side, persistence within onDestroy() will finish, as that is allowed to finish before the process can be killed.

Comment: Mark. To be compeltely hones what I'm trying to persist is instance of HtmlClient and possibly some derived objects. THese are fairly complex and may not be serializable. Why? For example, HttpClient gets initialized with some numbers of cookies that I need to retain to succesfully proceeed with session that is created for me on some application server out there. What do I do?